# Can non-American PhD students stay in the United States during the academic year 2020-2021 if all their classes are online?

Tags: usa, working, students, covid-19

I'm reading on https://thehill.com/homenews/administration/506072-ice-tells-students-on-visas-they-must-leave-us-if-schools-go-online ([mirror](https://web.archive.org/web/20200707183933/https://thehill.com/homenews/administration/506072-ice-tells-students-on-visas-they-must-leave-us-if-schools-go-online)) that the US government has the bright idea to refuse students of purely online courses (e.g., Harvard University) to stay in the US for the 2020-2021 academic year. Does that impact PhD students in computer science? I'm asking for this specific population as
one could argue that PhD students need to meet their advisors face to face on a regular basis, though computer science typically doesn't require a student to physically access a lab and meetings with advisors can be done online (sometimes less conveniently for people uncomfortable with using online shared whiteboards).

Comment: The effect of this recently announced change is unknown. A related issue has been raised here: https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/53034/how-will-phd-students-who-have-no-course-requirements-anymore-be-affected-by-th

Comment: @DavidSupportsMonica Make announcements, think about the effects later. Great :-( (no criticism intended for your comment, thanks for the information, I am just fed up with how difficult it can be to live in the US as an "alien". Great way to blow the "brain drain".)

Comment: Here's more: https://arstechnica.com/tech-policy/2020/07/harvard-mit-sue-trump-admin-to-block-deportation-of-online-only-students/

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt Feel free to come to Canada, where we like immigrants and don't do **** like this.

Comment: The "administration" has apparently changed its mind. https://www.sandiegouniontribune.com/news/nation-world/story/2020-07-14/trump-administration-rescinds-rule-barring-foreign-students-from-taking-all-classes-online-this-fall

Comment: @DavidSupportsMonica Great, thanks! Hopefully that non-sense will end here.

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt This nonsense might, but I'm sure there'll be more to come.

Comment: @DavidSupportsMonica Agreed. By the way you would come to convert your comment into an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The administration [has changed its mind](https://www.nytimes.com/2020/07/14/us/coronavirus-international-foreign-student-visas.html?searchResultPosition=5), and rescinded the rule change.

Comment: Thanks! You're welcome to post the same answer to [Can non-American students enrolled in a US university but attending only online courses (COVID) do a summer 2021 internship in the US via CPT or OPT?](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/q/20734/164)